# In Sass, how can I check if a list of arguments is empty?

Tags: sass, dart-sass

In Sass we can use [argument list](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists#argument-lists) but how can we check if this argList is empty or not?

Here a basic sample with some debugs :

```
@mixin mymixin($myargs...) {
    @debug $myargs;
    @debug type-of($transitions);
    @debug not $myargs;
    @debug $myargs == ();
    @debug $myargs == list;
    @debug $myargs == arglist;
    @debug $myargs == "";
    @debug $myargs == false;
    @debug $myargs == null;
    @debug $myargs == (null);
    @debug $myargs == [];
    @debug $myargs == array;
}
html {
    @include mymixin();
}
```

returns :

```
Debug: ()
Debug: arglist
Debug: false
Debug: false
Debug: false
Debug: false
Debug: false
Debug: false
Debug: false
Debug: false
Debug: false
Debug: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Length of lists can be achieved by using the `length` method of SASS. if `length($myargs)` is zero, it means the list is empty. More information about `length`:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list#length

```
@mixin mymixin($myargs...) {
    @debug length($myargs) == 0;
}
html {
    @include mymixin();
}
```